# li highlight next child on :hover

Tags: css

[Plunker:](https://plnkr.co/edit/Onb3pzyxcFbRTW5MWMv4?p=preview)

I have a simple ul:

```
 <ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li>item 5</li>
</ul>
```

When mouse hover on an li i need to highlight the next one (dynamically).

Thanks
Avi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple, use the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) (`+`).

```css
li:hover + li {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks alot.
What about if i want to select the previous li instead of the next one?

Comment: @אVי For that you would need to use [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) (something like `li:has(+ li:hover)`), but it [isn't supported by any browser yet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#Browser_compatibility).